# Basic Vertex Buffer Example not working

Tags: c, opengl

Im about to implement a very basic render module. now is time to change the old way to render primitives to a modern approach using VBO , so far i understand how it works but i cant get my PoC working.

Loading the basic model( a triangle) no opengl errors generated (glBindVertexArray is a macro to glBindVertexArrayAPPLE) :

```
    float pos[] = { 
    -1.0f, -1.0f,-5.0f, 
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,-5.0f, 
    };

printf("%d %d", map_VAO, map_VBO);
checkGLError();
glGenVertexArrays(1, &map_VAO);

checkGLError();
glGenBuffers(1, &map_VBO);

printf("%d %d", map_VAO, map_VBO); // here with 4.1 map_VAO is 0

checkGLError();
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glBindVertexArrays(map_VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, map_VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(float), &pos[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL); 

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArrays(0);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

return 0;
```

And in the main loop (drawing part) :

```
// .. clear buffers load identity etc... 

glColor3f(0.33f,0.0f,0.0f);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, map_VBO);
glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(map_VAO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); 

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); 

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(0);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

New drawing part : (removing unnecessary clientstate and binds)

```
glColor3f(0.33f,0.0f,0.0f);

glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(map_VAO);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

But nothing is displayed. I had tried changing the profiles and the OpenGL Version but other problems arise. 
I can draw a simple triangle with the old approach:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(  1.0f, 1.0f,-5.0f);
glEnd();
```

Questing: What I'm doing wrong?, theres some kind of activation related to VBO and VAO?

Additional questions : why when i use open gl 4.1 Core profile i cant get a VAO name with genVertexArray? (it says invalid operation)

Answer (score 5):

A few things:

1. `glEnableClientState` is deprecated. `glEnableClientState` is used to tell OpenGL you're using a vertex array for fixed-function functionality which you're not using anymore, so it's no use calling this function (and probably causes weird results).
2. `glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);` There is no need to enable it again in your drawing function. Enabling the 0th vertex attribute was stored in your VAO.
3. `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, map_VBO);` Also, no need to call this function in the drawing function. `glVertexAttribPointer` stores the VBO binding while you configured the VAO.

So, remove the `glEnable/Disable-ClientState` functions and remember that you just need to bind the VAO in your case. I believe the cause of your error is point 1. Points 2 and 3 are just to improve your code ;)

Comment: thanks for the tips, I did the cleaning that you pointed out, but Im still without my triangle. the old way still works fine.

Comment: hmm interesting. I see you mention that `glGenVertexArrays` sets map_VAO to 0. It should be greater than 1. You probably then get a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error (try to check for that).
In that case, what is your map_VAO variable? Is it an unsigned int as it should be? or an array of unsigned ints?

Comment: I only get 0 in map_VAO when i use other profile (4.1 core) both variables are GLuint

Comment: Weird. Are you sure you're running an OpenGL core context? Because if so, you shouldn't be able to use the old-approach in your case. It could be that your context is switched to a legacy context that doesn't support VAOs (Mac OS X does this if you didn't explicitly specify a core profile). Otherwise, I don't know what's causing the error. 

EDIT: I see Andon M. Coleman, just created an answer for this specific case: follow his instructions and you should get your triangle :)

Answer (score 4):

You did not wrap `glGenVertexArrays` around `glGenVertexArraysAPPLE` did you? (like you mentioned doing for `glBindVertexArray`)

That function does not exist in core profiles on OS X, you will notice a distinct lack of `GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object` from the extensions string. It exists in Legacy (2.1) profiles [as seen here](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1090.html) but not in Core (3.2+) [as seen here](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/index.html).

You are supposed to `#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>` when using a core profile on OS X and call `glGenVertexArrays (...)` instead of `glGenVertexArraysAPPLE (...)`.

Only call `VertexArray*APPLE` functions in an OpenGL 2.1 context on OS X or you will get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` errors.

Comment: im a little bit lost with the versions on opengl, first my glGetString version returned OpenGL Version : 2.1 NVIDIA-10.0.43 310.41.05f01, when i include gl3.h alone i get compiler warnings :

      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/gl.h|5 col 2 warning| gl.h and gl3.h are both included.  Compiler will not invoke errors if using removed OpenGL functionality.

Comment: Yeah, you're not supposed to include both `gl.h` and `gl3.h`. Basically, when you are building your software to run in OpenGL 2.1, you should include `<OpenGL/gl.h>` and when you are building it fore core 3.2+ (this includes GL4) then you should include `<OpenGL/gl3.h>`. It's designed that way so that you cannot accidentally use functions that aren't defined in the version of OpenGL you're trying to use. But if you include both, then that benefit goes away.

Comment: IM using glfw to set the version of opengl when i use 2.1 it compiles witho no warnings and nothing is displayed. when i use 3.2 forward compat compiles with warnings (about gl3.h and gl.h both included, even when i have only gl3.h. when i go core,  it fails with invalid operation on glLoadIdentity calls , and the version showed is 4.1

Comment: Yes, `glLoadIdentity` is invalid in a core profile. Basically everything that OpenGL 3.0 marked as deprecated is _removed_ from core profiles. If your code relies on things like `glLoadIdentity` (or any matrix function not related to shaders), then it will not work in a core profile.

Comment: Ok it seems that with 2.1 VBO is not working for me even when i have no errors at all  with glGetError , VBO related functions : gl*APPLE not working, upgrading the version to 3.2 forces me to use core profile, then i have to change every matrix function. =/